# How can I use a second USB keyboard for special keys under Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard

I'd like to use a second USB keyboard connected to my box running Ubuntu to generate special keystrokes. I'd like to map those in Vim to very specific actions.

I plug both my main keyboard and the secondary keyboard on two different USB ports.

How can I configura Ubuntu so that the keystrokes of only one of the keyboards are mapped to different keycodes?

For example, when I press the letter A on keyboard 2, I'd like it to appear as if I had pressed `XF86XK_Launch0`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sufficiently recent Ubuntu, you should be able to add your keyboard to `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/`.  The required format can be cribbed from `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`.

After adding your new mapping, you need to rebuild the hwdb.bin file: `udevadm hwdb --update`.  The next time `udev` sees your second keyboard (e.g. unplug and replug), it should load the mapping you wrote.

This is all assuming that your second keyboard has a distinct USB vendor:product pair to your first keyboard.  If the two are identical, you might need more involved rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d` (check `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules` for a starting point).

Also, look at `/lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules` if you're running X.